# How to wait for Subject.onNext(o)?

Tags: java, rx-java

There is `RxBus` implementation:

```
public class RxBus<E> {

    private final Subject<E, E> subject = new SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.<E>create());

    public void post(E o) { subject.onNext(o); }
    public Observable<E> observe() { return subject; }
}
```

Typical subscriber:

```
dataEventsBus.observe()
        .compose(RxP.ofTypes(
                DataEvent.Participant.Edit.class,
                DataEvent.Participant.Approved.class
        ))
        .flatMap(dataEvent -> updateParticipantCache())
        .subscribe();
```

Typical poster:

```
public void createTransactionsByAllocation(..., Subscriber<List<Transaction>> subscriber) {
    projectSession.getProject()
            .flatMap(project -> ...)
            .doOnCompleted(() -> dataEventsBus.post(new DataEvent.Participant.NewPayment()))
            .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
            .observeOn(mainThreadScheduler) // I want this Observabel to be compleated only
            .subscribe(subscriber); // when all bus's subscriber will be completed
}
```

Can I wait for all Bus's subscribers somehow?

It looks like I must make posting events part of the chain. Like `.flatMap(dataEventsBus.post(new DataEvent.Participant.NewPayment()))`. How can I implement it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'all subscribers'? How would you formally define the event you'd like to wait for?

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy I want `dataEventsBus.post(event)` to be blocking or processed as part of flow.

Comment: Sorry. I don't get it. Try rewording it. Or write full test case code that currently fails but you want it to succeed.